# Installing R and getting error

Tags: r

I am getting this error when installing R and did not get it before(was able to download it before but not anymore)

I would appreciate any help as I am new to Ubuntu.

```
 Failed to fetch http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/R/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu/vivid/r-doc-html_3.2.2-1vivid0_all.deb
 Could not resolve 'lib.stat.cmu.edu'
```

Answer (score 0):

DNS server might fail to resolve the name `lib.stat.cmu.edu`. You can try some public DNS like [Google's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Public_DNS) `8.8.8.8` (`2001:4860:4860::8888` for IPv6). To do that you can temporarily replace your `/etc/resolv.conf` with the following:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

To do this execute:

```
sudo su
mv -v /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf.bak
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf
```

To restore your original `/etc/resolv.conf` after the testing do:

```
sudo mv -vf /etc/resolv.conf.bak /etc/resolv.conf
```

For longer term, you can append Google's DNS to your set of nameservers by:

```
sudo su
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: Ok thank you, but how do you replace this exactly..... I am very new with coding in the terminal.

Comment: @PeteChernek: I've updated the answer

Comment: I tried it but still getting the same error when installing R

Comment: @PeteChernek: that's weird, for me `"host lib.stat.cmu.edu"` works fine on 8.8.8.8 and on my default DNS server, so it's not that the site is down. Does this command work for you?

Comment: pete2323@sc-8560w:~$ host lib.stat.cmu.edu
lib.stat.cmu.edu is an alias for FRET.stat.cmu.edu.
FRET.stat.cmu.edu mail is handled by 10 TEMPER.stat.cmu.edu.

Comment: That is what it said when I put in host lib.stat.cmu.edu

Comment: I am not sure what to do lol

Comment: That's weird, the host is resolving properly. You can also check `"host temper.stat.cmu.edu"` to see if an IP number comes up. Wonder what `apt` is doing so that it cannot see host that is normally visible.

Comment: Let me know if you can solve cause I am going to bed talk to you tommorrow Thanks!

Comment: `wget htttp://the-address-to-deb-you-gave` also fails. Adding `"lib.stat.cmu.edu 128.2.12.66"` to `/etc/hosts` doesn't help. It seems that cmu.edu have their DNS wrongly configured, you must wait for them to fix that.

Comment: This is the full error I am getting when runnin sudo apt-get install r-base-core:

Comment: WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  r-base-core r-base-dev r-cran-boot r-cran-mass r-cran-class r-cran-cluster
  r-cran-codetools r-cran-foreign r-cran-kernsmooth r-cran-lattice
  r-cran-matrix r-cran-nlme r-cran-mgcv r-cran-nnet r-cran-survival
  r-cran-rpart r-cran-spatial r-doc-html r-recommended
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
Err http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/R/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu/ vivid/ r-doc-html 3.2.2-1vivid0
  Could not resolve 'lib.stat.cmu.edu'